# Compare one element from one table in another one and return column

Tags: r

Hi I have a really tricky problem.
I tried several approaches and so far I got lost.

I have a table with one column which contains 9 and 2.

This is the second table:

```
> my_crazy_data
   V1 V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
1   1  a 2.0 3.0 4.0 9.0 6.0
2   1  b 0.2 0.1 0.8 0.9 0.2
3   1  c 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.1 0.8
4   1  d 0.1 0.1 0.3 0.1 0.4
5   2  a 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
6   2  b 0.1 0.4 0.3 0.5 0.7
7   2  c 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.5 0.8
8   2  d 0.2 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.9
9   3  a 8.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
10  3  b 0.1 0.4 0.3 0.5 0.7
11  3  c 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.5 0.8
12  3  d 0.2 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.9
```

Now I want to take the first element from the first table (in this case 9) and find it in the first row V3-V7 as V1 is the index. Once I found 9 (in this case V6) I want to return all V6 for the index V1=1  with V1 and V2 so  a result would look like:

```
1 a 9.0
1 b 0.9
1 c 0.1 
1 d 0.1
```

then proceed the second element from table1 (in this case 2) and same procedure but only search in the first row that has the first V1=2 so I would search for 2 in line 5 and once I found it 
only output the columns for index V1=2 so a result would look like:

```
2 a 2.0
2 b 0.4
2 c 0.4
2 d 0.5
```

How can I do that? Please help - any method would ok.

Thank you xx

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
d <- read.table(text='   V1 V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
1   1  a 2.0 3.0 4.0 9.0 6.0
2   1  b 0.2 0.1 0.8 0.9 0.2
3   1  c 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.1 0.8
4   1  d 0.1 0.1 0.3 0.1 0.4
5   2  a 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
6   2  b 0.1 0.4 0.3 0.5 0.7
7   2  c 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.5 0.8
8   2  d 0.2 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.9
9   3  a 8.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
10  3  b 0.1 0.4 0.3 0.5 0.7
11  3  c 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.5 0.8
12  3  d 0.2 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.9', header=TRUE)

# Your vector of values to look up    
v <- c(9, 2, 4)

# Split the second table by V1    
d.split <- split(d, d$V1)

do.call(rbind,
        mapply(function(x, y) {
          setNames(x[, c(1:2, 2 + match(y, x[1, -(1:2)]))], 
                   c('V1', 'V2', 'val'))
          }, d.split, v, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
)

#      V1 V2 val
# 1.1   1  a 9.0
# 1.2   1  b 0.9
# 1.3   1  c 0.1
# 1.4   1  d 0.1
# 2.5   2  a 2.0
# 2.6   2  b 0.4
# 2.7   2  c 0.4
# 2.8   2  d 0.5
# 3.9   3  a 4.0
# 3.10  3  b 0.5
# 3.11  3  c 0.5
# 3.12  3  d 0.7
```

Comment: thank you but:  Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , c(1:2, 2 + match(y, x[1, -(1:2)]))) : undefined columns selected

Comment: could it be my vector v? It has more values (270) than my table2 rows

Comment: I think its not the code snippet - I think it is my table. Table2 is not a 'traditional' table. It is read-in table2 <- read.table("mydata.txt",header=FALSE,nrows=5) but mydata has lines of text and its the lines which cause trouble I think. As soon as I split this table the subsets don't have column headers.

Comment: How can I return 0 if it does not find an element in the second table?

Comment: if I do do.call(rbind,
        mapply(function(x, y) {
          setNames(x[, c(1:2, 2 + match(y, x[1, -(1:2)],nomatch = NA_integer_, incomparables = NULL))], c('V1', 'V2', 'val'))
        }, d.split, v, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
) it still says: Error undefined columns selected - I am missing some small detail, please help?

Comment: @LillyKuil - I think I misunderstood your problem. I thought you wanted to look for element 1 of `v` in the first row of the subset of `d.split` where `V1==1`, look for element 2 in the first row of the subset where `V1==2`, and so on. Perhaps you can include an example of `v`.